# ng-repeat outputting unusual results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following code:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in workflow.flow | orderBy:'+step_number'">
    index: {{$index}}  - 
    step: {{ data.step_number }} - 
    arrayStep: {{ workflow.flow[$index].step_number }}
</div>
```

What I get back is the following, which makes NO SENSE:

```
index: 0 - step: 1 - arrayStep: 1
index: 1 - step: 2 - arrayStep: 2
index: 2 - step: 3 - arrayStep: 4
index: 3 - step: 4 - arrayStep: 5
index: 4 - step: 5 - arrayStep: 3
```

In theory, step and arrayStep should be exactly the same but I have no idea why it isn't so.

Does anyone know why this would be happening?

---

### **$scope.workflow.flow**

```
[
  {
    "id":"1334f68db820f664",
    "step_number":1,
    "tasks":[ { "id":"1334f68e3f20f665" } ]
  },
  {
    "id":"1349735b4720857a",
    "step_number":2,
    "tasks":[]
  },
  {
    "id":"134967a5ba205f5b",
    "step_number":4,
    "tasks":[ { "id":"134972c5b420e027" } ]
  },
  {
    "id":"1334f68e7d209ae6",
    "step_number":5,
    "tasks":[ { "id":"1334f68ef6209ae7" } ]
  },
  {
    "id":"13496c4b2a208575",
    "step_number":3,
    "tasks":[]
  }
]
```

Comment: Why would you expect them to be the same? Applying an `orderBy` filter on the `ng-repeat` does not alter the order of the items in the `$scope.workflow.flow` array. It simply controls the order in which they appear in the view.

Comment: So how do I get the real array index of where data actually is in ng-repeat, I was under the impression it was `$index` @Lex

Comment: I posted an answer how you could use `.indexOf()` to determine the item's position in the original array.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-repeat` creates a new scope and `$index` is just a simple "loop counter", if you will. Applying an `orderBy` filter in an `ng-repeat` will not change the order of the elements in the array being looped, it simply controls the order in which they are displayed in the resulting output. If you need the actual index of the array elements you'll have to use `.indexOf()`. Here is an example:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.workflow = {
      flow: [{
        "id": "1334f68db820f664",
        "step_number": 1,
        "tasks": [{
          "id": "1334f68e3f20f665"
        }]
      }, {
        "id": "1349735b4720857a",
        "step_number": 2,
        "tasks": []
      }, {
        "id": "134967a5ba205f5b",
        "step_number": 4,
        "tasks": [{
          "id": "134972c5b420e027"
        }]
      }, {
        "id": "1334f68e7d209ae6",
        "step_number": 5,
        "tasks": [{
          "id": "1334f68ef6209ae7"
        }]
      }, {
        "id": "13496c4b2a208575",
        "step_number": 3,
        "tasks": []
      }]
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="data in workflow.flow | orderBy:'+step_number'">
    index: {{$index}} - step: {{ data.step_number }} - arrayStep: {{ workflow.flow.indexOf(data) }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is totally correct, just explain a little like you did in comment, Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, @PankajParkar. Please feel free to edit if you see fit as well. I don't mind. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to output the ordered list to a new variable and go from there:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in orderedList = (workflow.flow | orderBy:'+step_number')">
    index: {{$index}}  - 
    step: {{ data.step_number }} - 
    arrayStep: {{ orderedList[$index].step_number }}
</div>
```

You can now referece `ordered` as the newly ordered list.

Comment: Instead I'd say use alias for filtered result like `ng-repeat="data in workflow.flow | orderBy:'+step_number' as orderedList"`

Comment: @PankajParkar -- Yeah that'll work to - I didn't see a mention of the Angular version above - your syntax is 1.3+

Answer (score 0):

Your are right @Lex Let me extend your answer a bit. I think this will meet your requirement @bryan

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.workflow = {
      flow: [{
        "id": "1334f68db820f664",
        "step_number": 1,
        "tasks": [{
          "id": "1334f68e3f20f665"
        }]
      }, {
        "id": "1349735b4720857a",
        "step_number": 2,
        "tasks": []
      }, {
        "id": "134967a5ba205f5b",
        "step_number": 4,
        "tasks": [{
          "id": "134972c5b420e027"
        }]
      }, {
        "id": "1334f68e7d209ae6",
        "step_number": 5,
        "tasks": [{
          "id": "1334f68ef6209ae7"
        }]
      }, {
        "id": "13496c4b2a208575",
        "step_number": 3,
        "tasks": []
      }]
    };
  });
```

```html
  

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
      <div ng-repeat="data in orderedList = (workflow.flow | orderBy:'+step_number')">
    index: {{$index}}  - 
    step: {{ data.step_number }} - 
    arrayStep: {{ orderedList[$index].step_number }}
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: While this will work to make the two values `step` and `arrayStep` match, if the the OP truly wants the index of the item in the original array this won't provide that. The question is unclear on the intention, though, so it's difficult to tell what the OP is really trying to accomplish.